# FullScreen at Google Play Game Services

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I have an application that displays all screens with the theme "Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" but when I go to log into google, the notification bar appears. Is it possible to make it disappear?

The screen where I have the button "login" has the theme "Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Thank you.